# ng-pattern is allowing trailing period

Tags: angularjs, regex

I'm trying to create a HTML number input with angularjs that only allows whole numbers, no decimals. It works for numbers that have a decimal component to the number, e.g. "3.5", but not numbers with only a trailing decimal but no number after it, e.g. "3."

The pattern I'm using is `"/^\d+$/"`, i.e.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
```

If I input "3." then the validation message does not appear. I expect it should.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xgcvLnh/):

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="number" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required>
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with `type="number"`.

In HTML, when `type="number"`, `3.` is a valid value. So, I believe `type="number"` is getting preference over `ng-pattern` regex.

Change type to `text`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krteja/p040khbx/)

Comment: Interesting. I'd updated my fiddle to declare the pattern in the scope and then use it as a literal in the html and it doesn't work with that, but yes, your fiddle does work.

Comment: I guess I missed something then. Thanks.

Comment: While this solution does solve the asked question, it means I can no longer prevent input of non-numeric characters in the input, so it's not really something I can use at face value.

Comment: Yes.. if you use angular pattern you will be *able* to enter invalid value.. but validation will trigger and notify user..

Answer (score 0):

If you need to disallow non-numeric input, just add a `onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57"`:

```js
function formCtrl($scope){
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        alert("form submitted");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="price" name="price_field" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required> 
    <span ng-show="myForm.price_field.$error.pattern">Not a valid number!</span>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: The angularjs [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) says "The validator sets the pattern error key if the ngModel.$viewValue does not match a RegExp". I can't seem to get it working as described. Maybe it's a bug in angularjs?

Comment: Ok, I see, I suggest to keep the ng-pattern (since a user can *paste* wrong data into the input field) and add an `onkeypress` attribute to the input to disallow *live* non-numeric input.

Comment: So, any feedback? What did you choose? Please let me know if I need to remove the post.